# Can a Pdf having cyclic indirect references a valid PDF?

Tags: c#, itext

[image]

Just to explain it further.
I have a Pdf with Internal structure define as following:(Please refer the Image)

```
Catalog
   Page
    Kids
      0000
        Resources
           XObject
             Form1  7 [2 0 R]
               Resources
                 XObject
                    Image1 3 [4 0 R]
                    Image2 5 [6 0 R]
                    Image3 7 [2 0 R]
```

Form1(parent) and  Image3(child) are referencing the same Indirect Reference 7 [2 0 R]

When we are reading the pdf structure from XObject to Resource and then XObject defined in that Resources by indirect reference Id. This is causing a cyclical reference and hence causing infinite looping.
Is it a valid Pdf? Opening pdf is not an issue in Adobe Acrobat Pro/Dc or any other application.

How to Resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know such a construct is not explicitly forbidden. Thus, PDF processors are expected to prevent unending recursions.

For example:

> While trying to collect all the XObject, it is causing infinite looping. How to Resolve it?

In your use case of collecting XObjects, you can simply check whether you already have collected the XObject you currently visit. If you have, you don't need to add it and you don't need to recurse into its resources again.

In general one has the choice of keeping track of the visited objects (e.g. by collecting them or by flagging them) or recursing only to a fixed maximum depth. The latter option may miss out on certain details but is easier to implement, no need to keep a possibly large set of visited objects somewhere; the former is more exact but also requires more resources.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I have an AI V24 file that calls an XObject, and that XObject calls itself recursively. Illustrator displays it properly but Acrobat Reader does not.

Comment: Well, recursively used XObjects are something that viewers *somehow* have to deal with without going into endless loops. Nonetheless, different programs may have different strategies to deal with such a situation with different rendering results. Thus, as a pdf creator one should avoid such constructs.

Comment: No doubt. Yet, Adobe Illustrator has created exactly that. My immediate concern is reading and displaying those XObjects correctly.

Comment: You probably should make that a question in its own right and share the PDF in question. You call proper what Illustrator shows and not proper what Acrobat Reader shows, most likely because you want to have shown what Illustrator shows. Probably both are right in their own way, probably neither one is...